# Calculate minimum energy of incident neutrino using Mandelstam variables

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, invariants

I am studying the following nuclear reaction:

$v + \tilde{v}\rightarrow Z^0$

where the antineutrino is motionless and has a given mass. The $Z^0$ boson has also a known mass. I'm trying to calculate the minimum enegy of the incident neutrino for the reaction to take place.

I am using the Mandelstam $s$ variable as following:

$s=(p_v+p_{\tilde{v}})^2=p_v^2+p_{\tilde{v}}^2+2p_v p_\tilde{v}$

At this point I need to make some assumptions that I'm not so sure about:

$p_v^2 = E_v^2-m_{0,v}^2 \simeq E_v^2$

Given than the energy of the incident neutrino is much bigger than its resting mass.

What about the antineutrino? Is it ok to write $p_\tilde{v}^2 \simeq E_\tilde{v}^2$ ? And what about the $s$ variable for the output of the reaction?

Based on the definition it's:

$s=p_{Z^0}^2=\left(\sum{E_i}\right)^2 - \left(\sum \vec{p}_i\right)^2$

In the coordinate system of center of mass it's $\left(\sum \vec{p}_i\right)^2=0$. Therefore:

$s=\left(E_{Z^0}^{cm}\right)^2$

Since the variable $s$ is invariant:

$E_v^2 + E_{\tilde{v}}^2 + 2E_vE_\tilde{v}=\left(E_{Z^0}^{cm}\right)^2$

I'm looking for the least energy $E_v$.

1. Are my assumptions for the approximations correct ?
2. How do I proceed from this point on?

Comment: *"What about the antineutrino? Is it ok to write $p^2_{\bar{\nu}} \approx E^2_{\bar{\nu}}$"*. You *know* the momentum of the antineutrino is zero.

Answer (score 1):

> Are my assumptions for the approximations correct ?

I think no. If you make the neutrino mass-less, such reaction cannot occur for your conditions, because the invariant made from left side is zero and from right side non-zero (Z boson mass squared).

You have to keep the neutrino mass in the game.

By the way you use the 4-vectors in a wrong way, e.g. it should be:

$p_v^2 = E_v^2-\vec{p_{v}}^2=m_v^2$

Comment: Recall that the system of two neutrinos can have non-zero mass no matter what the mass of the participants.